# iOS Swift - NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest cancel request

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, cancellation, sendasynchronousrequest

I'm trying to cancel an asynchronous request if there is a problem with the internet connection.

```
var connection: NSURLConnection!
self.connection = NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request2, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{

    (response, data, error) in ();
    if(response != nil){
    if let Data: AnyObject! ..... }
```

This is the code. I'm trying to cancel the request by:

```
self.connection.cancel()
```

but I have some errors : Cannot assing a value of type 'void' to a value of type NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 1):

`sendAsynchronousRequest` is a function that returns nothing, and yet you're assigning it to `self.connection`.

You don't need an `NSURLConnection` instance to send an asynchronous request--it is a class function, you pass it your `NSURLRequest`, and a custom `NSOperationQueue` or a `completionHandler`, optionally.

Also, you can't really cancel a request made through `sendSynchronous-` or `sendAsynchronousRequest`. You will need to make an `NSURLSessionTask`, to be used in combination with `NSURLSession`. `NSURLSessionTask`s have a `cancel()` method.